# Best way to emulate C type behavior in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c

### Context

My goal is to emulate the exact behavior of C integral types (assuming
a two-complement representation for signed types) in Javascript. To that
end, I keep the values in regular `number`s, not in typed arrays.
After an arithmetic operation, the value may overflow and I would like to
bring it back to the correct range by cutting off high bits.

Let's assume that we start with a variable `k`, which holds a `number`
(corresponding to a `double` in C), or a Javascript `BigInt` in case of a
64-bit integer in C (`long long`). That number may be outside the range and
I would like to cut off high bits.

I generally see two routes to achieve this. The first one is to store the
value in an item of a typed Array, like so (for signed 32-bit integers):

```
let a = new Int32Array(1);
a[0] = k;
k = a[0];
```

The second approach is to use a bitwise operator (one out of the two):

```
k &= 0xffffffff;
k |= 0;
```

A closely related alternative is an arithmetic approach like the following,
but it seems to be less efficient:

```
k -= 0x100000000 * Math.floor(k / 0x100000000);
```

Sadly, the modulo operator `%` alone does not suffice due to its handling of
negative numbers.
There is an even (much) slower mixed approach:

```
k -= Number(BigInt(k) & 0xffffffff00000000n);   // assuming overflows are not too large
```

So I will stick to basic bit masks.
I'd like to cover signed and unsigned integers from 8 to 64 bits. For the bit
masking approach I came up with the following "casting" expressions:

```
restriction to signed int8:      ((k << 24) | 0) >> 24
restriction to unsigned int8:    k & 0xff
restriction to signed int16:     ((k << 16) | 0) >> 16
restriction to unsigned int16:   k & 0xffff
restriction to signed int32:     k & 0xffffffff    or    k | 0
restriction to unsigned int32:   ((k - 0x80000000) & 0xffffffff) + 0x80000000
restriction to signed int64:     ((k + 0x8000000000000000n) & 0xffffffffffffffffn) - 0x8000000000000000n
restriction to unsigned int64:   k & 0xffffffffffffffffn
```

The last two cases assume that `k` is a `BigInt`.

### Benchmark

I must admit that I generally prefer the second approach since I expect it to
make the life of an optimizing JIT compiler much easier. However, at least
Firefox/Ubuntu shows a mixed picture:

```
int32 temp array: 2099ms
int32 bit masking: 427ms
uint32 temp array: 2068ms
uint32 bit masking: 7036ms
```

I find the last number disturbing.
Chromium is both faster and more consistent:

```
int32 temp array: 1774ms
int32 bit masking: 109ms
uint32 temp array: 1726ms
uint32 bit masking: 628ms
```

Test code:

```
{
    let k = 1234567890123.456;
    let a = new Int32Array(1);
    let start = (new Date()).getTime();
    for (let i=0; i<100000000; i++)
    {
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
    }
    let finish = (new Date()).getTime();
    console.log("int32 temp array: " + (finish - start) + "ms");
}
{
    let k = 1234567890123.456;
    let start = (new Date()).getTime();
    for (let i=0; i<100000000; i++)
    {
        k |= 0;
        k |= 0;
        k |= 0;
        k |= 0;
        k |= 0;
        k |= 0;
        k |= 0;
        k |= 0;
        k |= 0;
        k |= 0;
    }
    let finish = (new Date()).getTime();
    console.log("int32 bit masking: " + (finish - start) + "ms");
}
{
    let k = 1234567890123.456;
    let a = new Uint32Array(1);
    let start = (new Date()).getTime();
    for (let i=0; i<100000000; i++)
    {
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
        a[0] = k; k = a[0];
    }
    let finish = (new Date()).getTime();
    console.log("uint32 temp array: " + (finish - start) + "ms");
}
{
    let k = 1234567890123.456;
    let start = (new Date()).getTime();
    for (let i=0; i<100000000; i++)
    {
        k = ((k - 0x80000000) & 0xffffffff) + 0x80000000;
        k = ((k - 0x80000000) & 0xffffffff) + 0x80000000;
        k = ((k - 0x80000000) & 0xffffffff) + 0x80000000;
        k = ((k - 0x80000000) & 0xffffffff) + 0x80000000;
        k = ((k - 0x80000000) & 0xffffffff) + 0x80000000;
        k = ((k - 0x80000000) & 0xffffffff) + 0x80000000;
        k = ((k - 0x80000000) & 0xffffffff) + 0x80000000;
        k = ((k - 0x80000000) & 0xffffffff) + 0x80000000;
        k = ((k - 0x80000000) & 0xffffffff) + 0x80000000;
        k = ((k - 0x80000000) & 0xffffffff) + 0x80000000;
    }
    let finish = (new Date()).getTime();
    console.log("uint32 bit masking: " + (finish - start) + "ms");
}
```

### Question

Aside from speed, how do the approaches compare? I am looking for
technical and "operational" reasons for or against one or the other.
Are they safe? Good or bad practice? Am I overlooking something?
Maybe some of my expressions can be improved. Can you offer better
tricks? I would really love to see other people's ideas.

Comment: Couple of comments...  1) Note that Javascript includes both a BigInt64Array and BigUint64Array (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigUint64Array) which is likely more performant than BigInt.  2) Note that your benchmark might be heavily skewed due to Javascript compiler optimization that does away with a lot of your repetitive expressions.  Might be best to make use of a pseudo random number generator as part of your benchmark...